# Issues in "WP7" Sudden Tombstoning

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am facing some issues in WP7 tombstoning. My issue is application hangs when i try for a sudden tombstone and come back. ie, After loading the page i press device menu button and with in seconds i pressed back button( Pressed Back button before the actual page disappeared) In that time the page loads but the application hangs / its back key press is not working. and if we try for a slow thombstone it is working perfectly. And the pretty interesting thing is that, while tombstoning the loaded and unloaded events of APP working perfectly. Please any one help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Have you tried running with the Debugger attached?  If so what happens during the hang?  Can you hit Debug|Break All, and then Debug|Windows|Threads and examine the call stack of each thread to see if it is stuck, perhaps doing something on the UI thread that should be done on a background thread?

Comment: can you provide exact details fo how to repro this? What is on the page? What are you doing to cause tombstoning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your App has been deactivated, but not tombstoned. This results in neither the App or Page contrusctor being called, causing your app to act in unexpected ways. I highly recommend reading the [Windows Phone Silverlight Application Life Cycle](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/article/silverlight_application_life_cycle) document. The relevant extract for said article:

> This case can occur if the user
> presses the Start and Back buttons on
> the phone in quick succession. In this
> case, the application received a
> Deactivate event and the system was
> starting to save the state of the
> application to perform an application
> tombstone. Before this operation is
> completed, the app Activated event is
> received. The system knows that the
> application was not removed from
> memory, so the flow of execution is
> different. Specifically:
>
> •  The app constructor is not called.
>
> •  The page constructor is not called.
>
> The only way for the application to determine
> if this condition has occurred is to
> set a flag to indicate if the page
> constructor has been called. If you
> notice in the above section, this flag
> was set in the page constructor, and
> cleared in the OnNavigateFrom event.
> In this case, we will receive the
> OnNavigatedTo event, but we will see
> that the page constructor was not
> called. This tells us that our
> application was not tombstoned.